# How to install list of packages with file with comments

Tags: ubuntu, grep, apt-get

I want to organize a large file of dependencies with comments and newlines.  For example:

```
# Widget 1 dependences
package_a
package_b

# Widget 2 dependencies
package_x
package_y
package_z
```

This line seemed to make sense, but I don't understand why I'm getting error of unable to locate items from the list of exactly what I mean to print out:

```
E: Unable to locate package f2c gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libpcre3-dev libreadline-dev
```

It's like my entire whitespace-delimited list is being treated as one package.

```
  # Use 'strict mode', because i don't looove debugging
  #!/bin/bash
  set -euo pipefail
  IFS=$'\n\t'

  sudo apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" my_dependencies | tr "\n" " ")
  echo "$(grep -vE "^\s*#" my_dependencies | tr "\n" " ")"
```

Comment: But it's what you're telling it to do? It's not even unusual. As you can see by your output it seems like one of the packages is missing from the repos that are available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you translate the newline character, you have to use a field-separator that is valid under bash strict mode for the word-splitting to work.  tab or `\t` is chosen here:

```
sudo apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" my_dependencies | tr "\n" "\t")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have changed content of variable `IFS`. I recommend to reset your IFS variable to its default:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```